# PostCSS won't complie SCSS due to indentation?

Tags: css, webpack, sass, postcss

First time using this set up, but I can't seem to figured out why the .scss file won't compile after I add any styles.

I added

```
.test { color: #fff; }
```

And you can see in cmd line that it's not compiling, but I can't seem to figure out what it wants me to do.

> ERROR in  src/stylesheets/styles.scss
> 3:5  ✖  Expected indentation of
> 2 spaces           indentation
> 4:1  ✖
> Unexpected missing end-of-source newline
> no-missing-end-of-source-newline

[cmd line screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jP05c.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be asking for a 2 space indentation, you have either 4 spaces or a tab, so change that to 2 spaces and it also seems to be asking for a line feed at the end and you have none, so just add one of those and try again.

Answer (score 0):

It just needed one more extra line to be left as seen below
[image]